# Laragon phpmyadmin showing "Internal server error 500" with php-5.6.26-nts-Win32-VC11-x86

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, laragon

I am using Laragon 2.10 on Windows 10. I have added there another php non thread safe version: php-5.6.26-nts-Win32-VC11-x86 to use Zend guard loader extension. Because the extension works with only NTS php versions.

Anyway, Zend guard loader extension loaded successfully but localhost/phpmyadmin not working. What's problem there?

Please help me. Or give me a proper guideline: How to enable Zend guard loader extension at Laragon 2.10.

Comment: Are you using Laragon with Nginx or Apache?

Comment: @LeoKhoa  Laragon with Apache.